# Converting Lat/Long to Zip Code in r

Tags: r

When running this code:

```
library(ggmap)

ppt=read.csv("~/Downloads/PPT.csv")
test=ppt$the_geom
address=revgeocode(location=c(test),output="address")
```

I keep getting error:

> ```
> is.numeric(location) && length(location) == 2 is not TRUE
> ```

The columns for variable the_geom looks like this in csv file

```
- POINT (-73.8981682368399 40.74955730896312)
- POINT (-74.00004690644528 40.73207708606329)
- POINT (-73.98604698388607 40.732806345432046)
...
```

I'm guessing I get the error because of `POINT ()`. How can I fix this error?

Comment: `revgeocode` takes location in the format of `c(lon, lat)`, for example `revgeocode(c(-73.8981682368399, 40.74955730896312))`.

Comment: Your `the_geom` column is in Well-Known Text format. You need to parse this into separate columns of lons & lats.

Comment: `as.numeric(wellknown::wkt2geojson("POINT (-73.8981682368399 40.74955730896312)")$geometry$coordinates)` (you'd likely get more aid if you made a reproducible example and used `dput()` as the R tag faq suggests)